# UIPickerView number of rows

Tags: uipickerview

How can I get the number of items (rows) within a UIPickerView?  I cant seem to find a property that will tell me this.

Answer (score 1):

From [UIPicker documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)

@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger numberOfComponents

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;

Comment: I still dont get how I access that.  I did try numberOfComponents before and it always returns 1 even when I have multiple items.

Comment: Okay I figured it out, [myPicker numberOfRowsInComponent:0]

Answer (score 1):

Build a new PickerViewHelper file. Implement this required method for UIPickerViewDataSource delegate.

```
@interface PickerViewHelper : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

Then at UIViewController, get the number by:

```
long number = [self.yourPicker numberOfRowsInComponent : 0 ];
```